# How can i exclude a few columns when formatting a proc report?

Tags: sas, report

I am working on an excel report that is automatically generated by SAS and i need to have some of the columns formatted.

The dataframe has a format like this:

| category | subcategory | January | February | March |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Name | subname | 0 | 150 | 347 |

And i want the numbers in the month columns to have a red font only in case the number is not zero.

I am using the following code:

```
PROC FORMAT;
    VALUE NOK
        0  = 'BLACK'
        OTHER = 'RED';
RUN;

ODS EXCEL
file="/route/here/file.xlsx"
OPTIONS(SHEET_NAME="Report" SHEET_INTERVAL='NONE');

PROC REPORT DATA=MONTHS style(column)={foreground=nok.};
RUN;
```

However when i use this code the words name and subname are also in red. I would like to exclude those columns from the reporting format and i haven't figured out how to do that yet.

How can i either exclude those columns or modify my formatting code so only the months columns are formatted.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only apply it on the columns which need it.

```
data wide;
  length category subcategory $20;
  input category subcategory January February March;
cards;
Name subname 0 150 347
;

proc report data=wide;
 define January--March /style(column)={foreground=nok.} ;
run;
```

Or if it is easier set the other columns to black.

```
proc report data=wide style(column)={foreground=nok.};
 define category /style(column)={foreground=black} ;
 define subcategory /style(column)={foreground=black} ;
run;
```

[image]